# MVC Routing to call one view from another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

As explained already in my earlier posts I am newbie to MVC and I am developing a website. Everything works fine except for the little change that I did on my route.config file. I need to direct users to a view which is opened from a button on another view and is dependent on the parent view. It means it should not be allowed to be accessed independently.

**Editing it to be more clear.**

This is the problem.
customers login to my website and see their account activity page and once in they can choose to make a payment if they have any due amount. When they click on the payment button they are directed to the payment website and once they are done, they are redirected back to my website where they see a confirmation page/view.

So the URLs are like this right now.

```
http://www.examplesite.com/Homecontroller/Loginview/ - for login.
```

After login the URL is this

```
http://www.examplesite.com/Homecontroller/CustActview/
```

After returning from the payment site, the URL should be related to the custAct View because it is related to an account, So I want it to be as

```
http://www.examplesite.com/Homecontroller/CustActview/successfulpaymentview
```

so in order to achieve this I have added that other route in my route.config, but adding that has given me another problem, now if I login, the URL changes to this

```
http://www.examplesite.com/Homecontroller/CustActview/CustActview
```

So I m not sure how to handle this. Please help. Hope this is clear.

**Route.config**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Properties",
            url: "{controller}/CustAcct/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "HomeController",
                action = "successfulpaymentview",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        ); 
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "HomeController",
                action = "LoginView",
                id =
                    UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Comment: Edited it. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not necessary to add complexity in routing only to restrict direct access to that view.

Maybe, you should try using **Action Filters**.

Beyond that comment, in your route config you have defined two actions...

url: "{controller}/CustAcct/{action}/{id}",

- *CustAcct* and *{action}*

Try something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Properties",
            url: "Home/CustAcct/{param1}/{param2}/..."
        ); 
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Login",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

***Update:***

Ok, I get the idea! You RouteConfig.cs should be:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AccounInfo-Success",
                url: "{controller}/AccounInfo/{action}/"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

and your HomeController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult AccountInfo() {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Success() {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response...but I m not clear on what you suggested, can you please tell me how I can do that ?

Comment: my requirement in short is this, I have a http://myexample.com/home/accountInfo/ url and once users make the payment on the accountinfo page they are returned to a success url and I don want that success url to be example.com/home/success. I want it to be example.com/home/accountinfo/success. and that is what I m trying to get at.. any ideas ?